# gnuplot for loop with interval

Tags: loops, for-loop, gnuplot

I have the following gnuplot script that uses a for loop to plot 100 data sets of (x,y) format to one plot. However, the script only plots 2 data sets. Can anybody help? Thank you.

```
plotfile = "graph.eps"
set output plotfile
filename(n) = sprintf("%d_mod.int", n)
plot for [i = 400000:4000000:400000] filename(i) u 1:2 title sprintf("%d", i) w lp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a bug, which will be fixed in 4.6.6 and 5.0, see [#1429 Erratic behaviour of do for loops](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1429/) .

As a workaround you must iterate over smaller numbers:

```
plot for [i = 4:40:4] filename(i*100000) u 1:2 title sprintf("%d", i*100000) w lp
```

Comment: I renumbered my files to range from 1 to 100 and now the plot shows 100 data sets. Thank you for the help!

Comment: That's also fine :) So if this answer solved your problem you can accept it (click the gray check mark), see also http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers