# gnuplot for loop with large numbers

Tags: for-loop, gnuplot

I'm trying to use the for-loop construct in current gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 5 to plot several data files at once. The files are named like "file_1000000" from "file_0" up to "file_10000000" in increments of 1M. However, using

```
plot for [i=0:1e7:1e6] "file_".i
```

only draws file_0 and file_1000000 (1M). Thus I tried a simple loop such as

```
do for [i=0:1e7:1e6] {
  print i
}
```

resulting also in only 0 and 1M as output. Then I started to play with the increment number and the script prints the numbers up to the following values:

- 100 => all numbers up to 1e7
- 200 => all numbers up to 1e7
- 300 => none at all (?!)
- 400 => none at all
- 500 => up to 1410000
- 600 => up to 2841600
- 700 => none at all
- 800 => none at all
- 900 => up to 455400

Of cause I can circumvent this issue using something like

```
do for [i=1:10] {
  j=1000000*i
  plot "file_".j
}
```

but I'd like to understand what gnuplot does here. Does anyone know the reason for this odd behavior? I'd be grateful for any advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [gnuplot for loop with interval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282925/gnuplot-for-loop-with-interval)

Answer (score -1):

A [quote](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.6/gnuplot.pdf): "Multiple datafiles and/or functions may be plotted in a single command, separated by commas." on page 72.